# Measuring level of background noise in a recording of a known audio file being played in an environment

Tags: noise

I'm trying to solve the following scenario:

1. A digital music player plays audio in a public space
2. I have a microphone recording that audio in the space
3. I want to compare the noisy recording and the original sound file from the player to detect how loud my music is playing compared to the background noise. This way, I can adjust the volume up or down to match what's happening in the environment. Imagine a space that can get both quiet and noisy at different times of day.

Any idea what kind of algorithm can be used? Does anyone want to build it for me?

Thanks

Phil

Comment: After recording, take the original audio and recorded audio+noise side by side to an audio editor (Audacity as for an example), try match the levels of audio part and then turn the phase of the played audio file whole 180°. After doing these steps, when you play both the same time you should hear the noise part only.

Comment: This works, but not really as the playback environment is full of reverberation, echoes, etc... It's playing back in a grocery store with high ceilings, multiple speakers, etc.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you should time align the recorded audio with the played audio, especially when microphone is located far away from speakers.

Comment: You need to get a baseline measurement of the entire system response before you can start attempting something like this. The system response involves the relative impulse responses of the playback source, the recording device, and the room in question. Once you have determined the total impulse response, you can use that to filter the original audio and then try the 180-phase trick.